# Application Lifecycle Android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

i want method execute. if user out of my app (exit, not just out by Click on home button). and restart again.

i used `onRestart()`  and `onDestroy()`  and `onStop()`.

but they don't give me what i want.

I hope you understand my question successfully.

Comment: Can you try explain better what is your goal?

Comment: method execute  when user open an application a **second  time.**
and not execute on **first time**

Comment: Wow. Again. What is your question?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is to use `onPause()` and `onResume()` most likely

Comment: `onPause()` and `onResume()` worked if application work on background.<br>but i want method execute after user Exit the application permanently. <br> and Restart again

Comment: You could use SharedPrefs and set it to false on launch of the application and then check that flag in the `onResume()` of the first activity that is opened and if it is true, you can execute your logic and then set that flag back to false again